# Unable to access Wordpress site created as a Docker Stack

Tags: docker, wordpress, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a Wordpress site inside a Docker stack composed of the following services:

- `wordpress` - the Wordpress site itself
- `db` - the MySQL container

I have the following `stack.yml` file:

```
version: '3.1'
networks:
  abtehnic:
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - abtehnic
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: barbu123
  wordpress:
    image: abtehnic-wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: barbu123
    networks:
      - abtehnic
    volumes:
      - ./source:/var/www/html
```

I deploy the stack with the following command:

$ docker stack deploy -c stack.yml abtehnic

The `docker ps` command outputs the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
256e65fe2c4c        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp            abtehnic_db.1.mo0xp17adt2jocu9yivkzg19g
26481d8bab95        wordpress:4.8       "docker-entrypoint..."   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp              abtehnic_wordpress.1.tiikrjwm1kcmxjg7v74vrcquw
```

I am trying to find out the mapped port via:

```
$ docker port <container_id for wordpress>
```

and its output is empty. Also when I am running `docker logs <container_id_for_wordpress>` I get the following:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 22
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.1.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.1.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Oct 28 16:05:32.189285 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 28 16:05:32.189321 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why can't the `wordpress` container access the `db` container?
2. Why isn't there any port that I can use to access the Wordpress site from my host?

Comment: Check the logs for the db service to make sure it started: `docker logs abtehnic_db.1.mo0xp17adt2jocu9yivkzg19g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
depends_on:
  - db
```

That just makes sure the database container is fully loaded before the wordpress container. You need to tell docker to link the `db` container from the `wordpress` container to reference it by name.

What docker-compose does under the hood is take the ip docker gives the `db` container and add a `/etc/hosts` entry to the `wordpress` container so you can reference it by name.

So try adding this to the wordpress section

```
links:
  - db
```

Comment: Thanks man! This works! I don't get any errors in the `wordpress` container now! I still get empty output from `docker port` but I ran `docker service ls` and apparently it lists the ports there. Do you know why `docker port` outputs nothing?

Comment: You might need to list the port as `80:80` and not just `80`

Comment: no difference that way.

Comment: [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) only waits for the container to be started, not for it to be ready. Use [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) instead. Also [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) is no longer necessary. The service names are automatically added to each service's /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're doing something like `docker port 26481d8bab95`, as per your question you defined port 80, so your answer is port 80:

```
# docker run -d -p 80:80 wordpress
dc9e4aab1015eb5d82cf489e2943d76084faceaf3093bc3238964d6cfa81ab1c
# docker port dc9e4aab1015eb5d82cf489e2943d76084faceaf3093bc3238964d6cfa81ab1c
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
#
```

stack or not, you should still be able to use `docker port`

1. `mysqld` takes longer to start comparing to `httpd` (wordpress), that's why you're seeing errors
2. docker wise, it's configured correctly and the actual reason why you can't access it could be many, firewall and whatnot.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. My container is started by the stack, not manually.

Comment: @Victor I suggest you to re-write your question and make it clear as "what am I doing wrong" is not right question here...

Comment: I've just changed it!

Comment: If I run `docker stack ps <my_stack_name>` I see the two services launches but the `PORTS` column is empty